# getting Tomcat to look in subfolders

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

We have a Tomcat folder (on OS X) that uses the standard ROOT folder for our principal webapp.

ROOT contains all the standard components, notably META-INF and WEB-INF.

ROOT also contains hundreds of static files,  with suffixes such as  .js, .css, .png, etc.

Various servlets produce pages that reference these files, e.g. with the string "/castle.png". Tomcat knows to look for castle.png in ROOT.

This works but at a price: The numerous static files make ROOT appear cluttered to the admin. It would be nice to be able to collect the static files in special folders, e.g. the image files in a folder called "images", without invalidating the file reference, e.g. "/castle.png".

Such use of an images folder currently does invalidate the file references - unless, of course, we also edit and recompile the servlets themselves (e.g. replacing "/castle.png" with ""/images/castle.png").

I am looking for a way to configure Tomcat in a way that would make such editing and recompilation of our servlets unnecessary.

In other words: Is there a way to instruct Tomcat to look for (certain types of ) static files in (certain of) ROOT's subfolders?

I have a hunch it could be done in web.xml (url-mapping), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done thanks to the :

```
<url-pattern>
```

parameter in web.xml

Have a look at this arcticle:

http://java-espresso.blogspot.fr/2011/09/webxml-problem-and-solution-for-url.html